# How to pass variable to Azure DevOps Run Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-task

I am trying to put predefined value **RELEASE_RELEASENAME** to Azure DevOps Run Pipeline task, but it ends always with error: "##[error]Build parameters is not a valid json object array. Example valid object: [{"VAR1":"VALUE1","VAR2":"VALUE2"},{"VAR1":"VALUE1","VAR2":"VALUE2"}]"

[Azure Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsKeb.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try the change the expression of the variable like：
[{"var1": "$(Release.ReleaseName)"}]